# How do I prevent the JavaScript execution stack from getting filled by too many levels of recursion?

Tags: javascript, recursion

The following function hangs my Chromium browser on an input of `50` whereas it returns perfectly on a much lower input of `10` or so . I believe this results due to the fact that there are way too many levels of recursion which fill up the stack with recursive calls and don't allow the code to finish execution.

```
var Y = function (f) {
  return f(function (x) {
    return Y(f)(x);
  });
};

console.log(Y(function (f) {
  return function (n) {
    if (n === 0) {
      return 0;
    } else if (n === 1) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
    } 
  };
})(10)); // replace 10 by 50 to reproduce issue
```

JavaScript doesn't have tail call optimization like Scheme, for instance. So, how are we to write recursive functions in JavaScript that don't die on very large inputs?

*(Please ignore the `Y` function. That is just part of some learning that I am doing. The lambda passed to `console.log()` is equivalent to a simple explicitly recursive Fibonacci function.)*

http://jsbin.com/decusumoyiwa/1/edit

Comment: simple: don't recurse so much. there is NOTHING you can do in your code to affect the JS engine's internal limits, so your only choice is to refactor your code to not require such deep recursion.

Comment: You cannot prevent that in JavaScript any more than you can in C++ or Java.

Comment: memoization when your function is deterministic.

Comment: I could find the factorial of 50 using identical code in Scheme, owing to the tail call optimization. There are plenty of recursive calls, yes, but tail call optimization would reduce the stack to half and isn't available in JavaScript. Memoization is a great idea for functions that are referentially transparent. But what if the function isn't?

Comment: I believe the new function syntax in ECMAScript 6 will allow for proper tail calls. ...[*more info*](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proper_tail_calls)

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
var level = 0;

function f(n) {
  level++;
  if (level > 50) { // or another value other than 50
    throw '...';
  }
  var val = _f(n);
  level--;
  return val;
}

function _f(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 0;
  } else if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
  } 
}
```

Then use the `f` function like before, and you can use a try-catch block around the call to `f` to detect when the function has reached a too deep point.

(I did not test this but I think it would work)